# How to set up virtual hosts on Apache 2.2

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

Can anyone direct me to a good tutorial on how to set up virtual hosts using Apache 2.2?  Here's my situation:

I have Apache running on my laptop and I want two websites-- one on port 80 and one on port 8089.  I want to access each site from the other computer on my network by entering the computer's IP address, such as http://192.168.1.102 and http://192.168.1.102:8089.  Yet when I enter the second url, it directs me to the website running on port 80.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have 2 virtual hosts defined like this, but with differeing DocumentRoots:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.somecompany.com
    DocumentRoot "/docs/dummy-host.somecompany.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.somecompany.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.somecompany.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.somecompany.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.somecompany.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8089>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.somecompany.com
    DocumentRoot "/docs/dummy-host.somecompany.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.somecompany.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.somecompany.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.somecompany.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.somecompany.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Since I don't have any host names, what could I use for the following attributes-- My IP address?
ServerName dummy-host.somecompany.com
ServerAlias www.dummy-host.somecompany.com

Comment: The only thing that *really* matters is DocumentRoot. Im pretty sure (though not certain), that you could omit all other declarations and just point your browser to http://localhost:80 or http://localhost:8089 and you'll get the corresponding files being serveed from the appropriate DocumentRoot

Comment: I just tried what you said-- no difference.  Whether I type in http://localhost:80 or http://localhost:8089, I still see the same webpage I have at port 80 and not the one I have at port 8089.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to instruct Apache to listen on the ports you need:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8089
```

Second you need to tell it what to do with 80 and 8089 traffic:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /website/site80
    ServerName internet.dev
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8089>
    DocumentRoot /website/site8089
</VirtualHost>
```

Third you need to "allow" Apache to use those directories:

```
<Directory "C:/website/site80">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/website/site8089">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: It's still redirecting me to the site at port 80.  I really don't get it.